# Sort by upvotes in new navigation with custom tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, new-nav

In the new navigation UI, sort by upvotes is missing when I search for tags. It is only there under `popular` tab, but clicking that tab erases any search queries I have. Is it mis-design or hidden somewhere I haven't found?

Answer (score 3):

Sorting by votes is only available in "popular" by design, however filtering by tag in that tab was a feature request and we implemented it in alpha-2.